# Enable tomcat session persistence past session time-outs?

Tags: session, tomcat, timeout, persistence

I have configured JDBC session persistence in my local machine. Whenever a session is created, after a default time-out a database entry is made in an Oracle table. When the session is timed out, the entry for the session is removed from table.

Is it possible to make sessions persist even after a session times out? Persistent sessions should be removed from the database entry only if the user closes the browser.

Comment: Have you tried anything already? If so, detail your steps.

Comment: I have only made configuration for JDBC persistence setup (which is working fine). To handle session timeout persistence, are there any settings needed?